# return the only record value in a table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

ClientAccountAccess table will only ever have one record, containing an ID and a GUID.
I want to return the GUID as string.

```
private static string GetAccessCode()
{
    using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
    {
        string clientAccessCode = from e in db.ClientAccountAccesses
                                     where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.GUID)
                                     select e.GUID;

        return clientAccessCode;
    }
}
```

select is throwing an error saying cant convert Ienumerable to string, but I dont want to create an IEnumerable  clientAccessCode, as I said there will only ever be one record in this table and I want to return the value of the GUID.

?
thanks for replies

Comment: If there's only going to be one record, why are you bothering to filter? And filtering to only include null/whitespace values is particularly odd...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` if there should not be more than one matched result:

```
private static string GetAccessCode()
{
    using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
    {
        var clientAccessCodes = from e in db.ClientAccountAccesses
                                where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.GUID)
                                select e.GUID;

        return clientAccessCodes.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Note - result of query will be of type `IEnumerable<string>`. You also can use lambda syntax:

```
private static string GetAccessCode()
{
    using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
    {
        return db.ClientAccountAccesses
                 .Where(e => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.GUID))
                 .Select(e => e.GUID)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```